# Book recommendation: computability theory and Chomsky hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, chomsky-hierarchy

What is a good book for learning computability theory that covers the Chomsky hierarchy?

Comment: What is a good book or not is a matter of opinion.  See our [help/dont-ask].  What works best is to identify a list of (objectively evaluatable) requirements that a book must satisfy; and to do some research and show the list of books you've found and the extent to which they do or don't meet the listed requirements.  A good way to do research to identify potential books is to look at what textbooks are used in related courses at major universities, and look at Amazon reviews.